# Intel HDMI-1 disconnected Xrandr

Tags: intel-graphics, hdmi, intel, xrandr

I did a fresh install of Lubuntu 20.04, I had to use "graphic safe mode".
My monitor is showing the boot screen / BIOS.
If I add **nomodeset** to GRUB, it works with 800x600 resolution. It's a touchscreen with built in PC from RC Stars.

I installed TeamViewer when using "nomodeset". The monitor is completely black but I can reach the computer through TeamViewer.

Answers for this questions I've found after a day of googling doesn't help and the answers is quite similar.

**sudo lspci -v**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

**xrandr**

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*+
   1024x576      59.90    59.82  
   960x540       59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   640x360       59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --right-of eDP1**

```
Doesn't do anything
```

**uname -a**

```
5.8.0-45-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 23 13:46:31 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1920x1080**

```
xrandr: cannot find mode "1920x1080"
```

How do I troubleshoot to find out the problem? Windows installation works, but none of the Ubuntu distros/versions I've tried has worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your pc?
press alt+ctrl+F3 and login do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
Also have you downloaded the drivers if not that might also be the problem.

Comment: I have upgraded. I removed and reinstalled xserver-xorg-video-intel